# Cannon.js: Finding the side of a dice is using quaternions

Tags: javascript, 3d, cannon.js

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dethstrobe/o7ms50to/5/) with some of the code I'm working with.

I'm rolling the dice, not randomly yet, but that'll be added later. But right now I'm having a hard time to find out which side the dice has landed.

On line 352 in the JS, inside the tick function is where I'm trying to find out which side the dice landed on. I've tried several ways to look at the quaternion, but it never gives me the results I'm expecting. And I'm sure its because I don't know jack about quaternions. So any help would be much appreciated.

```
function tick() {
    world.step(timeStep);

    drawScene();

    if(cubeBody.velocity.norm() < 0.001) {
        var direction = cubeBody.quaternion.toAxisAngle()[0];

        console.log(direction);

        if (direction.x < 0.1 && direction.x > -0.1 &&
            direction.y < 0.1 && direction.y > -0.1) {
            console.log("side 1 or 6");
        } else if (direction.y > 0.1 &&
            direction.z < 0.1 && direction.z > -0.1) {
            console.log("side 2");
        } else if (direction.y < -0.1 &&
            direction.z < 0.1 && direction.z > -0.1) {
            console.log("side 5");
        } else if (direction.x > 0.1 &&
            direction.z < 0.1 && direction.z > -0.1) {
            console.log("side 3");
        } else if (direction.x > 0.1 &&
            direction.z < 0.1 && direction.z > -0.1) {
            console.log("side 4");
        } else {
            console.log("we got trouble");
        }
    } else {
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }

}
```

This code will probably end up using a switch or object key later, but for right now to help me "visualize" it, I have it as a horrible if statement. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the six local axes of the cube (+x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z) and transform them to world space using the `body.quaternion`, and check which of these vectors is "pointing up the most".

However, you'll get better performance if you transform the world up vector to local body space, and check which direction this vector is pointing locally.

Before your game loop:

```
var localUp = new CANNON.Vec3();
var inverseBodyOrientation = new CANNON.Quaternion();
var limit = Math.sin(Math.PI/4);
```

In your game loop:

```
// Transform the world up vector to local body space
localUp.set(0,1,0);
body.quaternion.inverse(inverseBodyOrientation);
inverseBodyOrientation.vmult(localUp, localUp);

// Check which side is up
if(localUp.x > limit){
    // Positive x is up
} else if(localUp.x < -limit){
    // Negative x is up
} else if(localUp.y > limit){
    // Positive y is up
} else if(localUp.y < -limit){
    // Negative y is up
} else if(localUp.z > limit){
    // Positive z is up
} else if(localUp.z < -limit){
    // Negative z is up
} else {
    // The box is not resting flat on the ground plane
}
```

The `limit` is chosen so that the local up vector must be within the top, bottom, right, left, front and back slices of a sphere with radius 1. See the gray areas in the picture below.

[image: The "up" regions to compare against.]

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do it is to create 6 sample points, one for each side of the dice. Those sample points should be exactly at the center of each face. For example, if your dice is a cube from (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1) then (1,0,0) is the center of "right" face of your dice and (-1,0,0) is the center of the "left" face of the dice.

After your dice landed, get the quaternion value of the dice. Transform each of those sample points by the quaternion. Go through each sample points, the sample point with the highest value in your up-axis is the side the dice landed.

Comment: Yeah, I talked with the creator of cannon.js and he recommend something similar.

I [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dethstrobe/o7ms50to/8/) with some code that logs which side the dice lands on. Thanks for the suggestion.